# Symbian C++ - Use a TTF font in your application?

Tags: c++, fonts, symbian, truetype

Is it possible to package a .TTF file in your application and use it to render text at runtime, and have the application release the font after use?

I've found bits of information scattered around the forum, but nothing conclusive.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer above is wrong. You can use TTF in symbian *without* converting it into GRD. I did it two years back on older versions of Symbian (probably 8).  Newer versions probably have built in support. In any case serch the net for a truetype font file driver for symbian (a .dll) file. Install it and you can use any TTF simply by copying it into the fonts folder.

Symbian has excellent support for fonts even for your own home built propitory formats. Just write a driver and install it. Symbian will scan the fonts directory and call each driver with each font file. Which ever driver can handle the font file extension responds and the font loads.

Comment: It wasn't my answer, I just tidied it up as it was a bit offensive :)

Comment: Surely writing a font driver isn't that easy?
Also, I'd recommend freetype for ttf rendering.